# Searching in .txt file with condition through php

Tags: php

In the .txt file:

```
---
FieldType: Text
FieldName: FirstName
FieldFlags: 0
FieldValue: Mehedee
FieldJustification: Left

---
FieldType: Text
FieldName: Age
FieldFlags: 0
FieldValue: 25
FieldJustification: Left
```

I wanted to get value after FieldValue: if the "FieldName: FirstName" before FieldValue.

I am able to parse value after "FieldValue:" but cannot if "FieldName: FirstName" remains, the after FieldValue: (Mehedee) should be got.
How can I do it?

Comment: Can you please edit the TXT file example to look exactly as you have it ? What are the "---" for ? Do they exist in your real file ? And ofcourse as stated by @Avery - please give you existing solution, what have you tried already?

Comment: I have got answer. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

meh.

First let's parse the data into something more manageable.

```
$all = file_get_contents('your/file.txt');
$rows = explode('---',$all);
$data = array();
foreach ( $rows as $row ) {
    $row = trim($row);
    if ( strlen($row) ) {
        $cols = explode("\n",$row);
        $rowArray = array();
        foreach ( $cols as $col ) {
            $parts = explode(':',$col);
            if ( isset($parts[0],$parts[1]) ) {
                $rowArray[$parts[0]] = trim($parts[1]);
            }
        }
        if ( count($rowArray) ) {
            $data[] = $rowArray;
        }
    }
}
```

you can see what it did:

```
print_r($data);
```

which outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [FieldType] => Text
            [FieldName] => FirstName
            [FieldFlags] => 0
            [FieldValue] => Mehedee
            [FieldJustification] => Left
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [FieldType] => Text
            [FieldName] => Age
            [FieldFlags] => 0
            [FieldValue] => 25
            [FieldJustification] => Left
        )

)
```

and then an example of one way to use it:

```
foreach ( $data as $row ) {
    echo 'field value is '.$row['FieldValue'];
}
```

and this outputs:

> field value is Mehedee
>
> field value is 25

*SO: don't hate me*

Comment: I have amend your code and get exact solution. Thanks a lot for your nice explanation.